# Is it possible that Krypton (Winforms library) has memory leak issues

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks, krypton

I' currently debugging a big Winforms application that's got some memory leak issues. I use the .NET memory profiler and so far I've been able to find some of those leaks and solve them. But now I am faced with a problem which I am not sure is a problem, and if it is one I don't know how to solve it.

After running my application for like 1 min (which is not a lot considering normal users could use it for hours),.NET memory profiler shows me around 100-200 instances of different controls from the Krypton Toolkit, and this number is increasing if I keep going (they are never garbage collected, because it appears they are still being referenced somewhere). Now if I check the root path of those instances and they all look like:

[image: Root path for Krypton ViewManager]

I don't know where to look in my code to make these instances be de-referenced correctly when they are not needed anymore, since I don't know what is still referencing the control. I know the place where the KryptonButtonEx gets created, and from what I understand the ViewManager is created by this button, but still I don't see what I can do about it. For those who are interested, the code to create the button is this:

```
        KryptonButton newControlButton = new KryptonButton();
        newControlButton.Tag = mtActivityControl;
        newControlButton.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        newControlButton.AutoSize = true;
        newControlButton.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly;
        newControlButton.ButtonStyle = ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.ButtonStyle.ListItem;
        newControlButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
        newControlButton.Name = string.Format("controlButton{0}", mtActivityControl.SymbolicName);
        newControlButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(96, 23);
        newControlButton.StateCommon.Content.Image.ImageH = ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.PaletteRelativeAlign.Near;
        newControlButton.StateCommon.Content.ShortText.TextH = ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.PaletteRelativeAlign.Near;
        newControlButton.TabIndex = 5;

        StringBuilder buttonText = new StringBuilder();
        buttonText.Append(Path.GetFileName(mtActivityControl.ControlName));
        /*if (mtActivityControl.SymbolicName.Length != 0)
        {
            buttonText.Append(" (");
            buttonText.Append(mtActivityControl.SymbolicName);
            buttonText.Append(")");
        }*/

        newControlButton.Text = buttonText.ToString();
        newControlButton.Values.ExtraText = "";
        newControlButton.Values.Image = null;
        newControlButton.Values.ImageStates.ImageCheckedNormal = null;
        newControlButton.Values.ImageStates.ImageCheckedPressed = null;
        newControlButton.Values.ImageStates.ImageCheckedTracking = null;
        newControlButton.Values.Text = buttonText.ToString();
        newControlButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.controlsButton_Click);
```

and even though it is not necessary from what my research told me, I unhook the event like this in the Dispose function:

```
newControlButton.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.controlsButton_Click);
```

So my question is:

Is it possible that Krypton itself keeps a reference to my controls which leads to some memory not being freed (which could be ok if it is a limited amount of memory used for keeping an object pool or something like that, but could be a problem if it is an uncontrolled memory leak)? If it doesn't come from Krypton, do you have an idea where to look to destroy those instances correctly?

Many thanks!

EDIT:

I just noticed that the class KryptonButtonEx doesn't come from Krypton but from my app. But I don't think it changes anything to the question since the only thing it does is override the GetPreferredSize function:

```
/// <summary>
/// An extended/fixed KryptonButton which handles resizing correctly.
/// </summary>
public class KryptonButtonEx : ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonButton
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the size of the preferred.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="proposedSize">Size of the proposed.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override Size GetPreferredSize(Size proposedSize)
    {
        // Do we have a manager to ask for a preferred size?
        if (ViewManager != null)
        {
            // Ask the view to peform a layout
            Size retSize = ViewManager.GetPreferredSize(Renderer, proposedSize);

            // Apply the maximum sizing
            if (MaximumSize.Width > 0) retSize.Width = Math.Min(MaximumSize.Width, retSize.Width);
            if (MaximumSize.Height > 0) retSize.Height = Math.Min(MaximumSize.Height, retSize.Width);

            // Apply the minimum sizing
            if (MinimumSize.Width > 0) retSize.Width = Math.Max(MinimumSize.Width, retSize.Width);
            if (MinimumSize.Height > 0) retSize.Height = Math.Max(MinimumSize.Height, retSize.Height);

            return retSize;
        }
        else
        {
            // Fall back on default control processing
            return base.GetPreferredSize(proposedSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you ask the Krypton Toolkit developers? If anyone would know it would be them.

Comment: I checked the forum and no one seems to be talking about this problem. I'll post a question right away though I don't know why I didn't think about it ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You posted the wrong code.  Instead of the code that *creates* the button, you should be very interested in the code that *removes* it.  Search for Controls.Remove and Controls.Clear and make sure that every control that is getting removed is being disposed.  Another diagnostic is TaskMgr.exe, Processes tab.  View + Select Columns and tick USER objects.  Seeing this number go up steadily is a hard clue that the code isn't disposing controls where is should.  This is the only case I know of not calling Dispose() causing a permanent leak.

Instead of Controls.Clear(), use code like this:

```
 while (panel.Controls.Count > 0) panel.Controls[0].Dispose();
```

Disposing a control also automatically removes it from the parent's Controls collection.

Comment: In fact I can see in the task manager that USER objects constantly go up. For the code where the button is removed, does something like if (components != null))
    {
      components.Dispose();
    }

Comment: (sorry pressed enter accidentally)...  automatically does everything to clean the button correctly?

Comment: Well, you found it.  Disposing the components isn't good enough, you have to dispose the controls.  Post updated with code snippet.

Comment: This solved it, thank you very much! :) Actually the Controls field doesn't seem to contain everything I have to dispose but if I manually call Dispose on every button in my control, it doesn't leak anymore.